# How to adjust brightness alternatively?

Tags: screen, htc-one-x, htc, screen-brightness, water-damage

What if system brightness control does not work ?

How to adjust brightness of android phone alternatively ?

I am on HTC One X. I just noticed my phone's system brightness control is not working as I recently got my phone repaired. My phone's display IC has been changed as display was not working as my phone got wet.

I doubt the one who repaired a phone changed display IC of other phone, that's why the brightness control is not working.

So, is there any alternative way to control the brightness in android phone ?

Whatever app so far I have installed regarding brightness control seems to do the same thing what system brightness control does. So, nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor) app by haxor industry. I use it primarily for keeping my screen dark at night for reading, but it may be a suitable temporary solution in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the brightness control in the hardware is broken. Perhaps when the mechanic installed it he didn't manage to connect the ribbon cable correctly. There's no way an app can work around such a hardware problem. You should return your phone to the mechanic and ask him to actually fix it this time.

Comment: At least a quick try couldn't hurt: There's [Screen Dim Trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.ScreenDim.Trial) to do that.

Comment: he says my display was damaged, and he somehow fixed the display, he says the display needs to be changed...

Comment: @hsuk Then maybe you can post a new answer and say that you will have the LCD display replaced (in case a software solution doesn't work for you). Then, don't forget to mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: @geffchang : I am still waiting for other answers though that won't gonna solve my problem. Replacing display could not be the answer as display is working fine ... I won't replace just display to get brightness control. It costs NRs. 6500.

Comment: @hsuk The LEDs or EL strips illuminating the display are part of the display module. You can't replace one or the other separately. If this isn't working because the person who installed your display got it wrong or used a faulty component, you shouldn't have to pay again for him to fix it.

Comment: All he says is I need to change the display, I think I have to use my mobile like this till display works fine. I don't know how he fixed the display... May be he carelessly did sthg that damaged the brightness control...